# table view always refreshes twice and fails at the 2nd time

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, ipad, tableview

I've got a FoodType class that reads a NSArray of Dictionaries from Property list. It stores the relationship of integer values and NSString names.

When I add a new record, I will init a record with default values, use FoodType class to retrieve corresponding strings and display them in the "add record view".

Every time I bring up the "add record" view (it's a tableview subclass), all the cells will be refreshed twice. (I found out this by having a breakpoint in cellForRowAtIndexPath).

Then it comes the problem. The debugger shows me that at the first time, the cells' texts are set properly. But the second time, the same piece of code fails to get the string. Fails means it returns nil. This is the code in cellForRowAtIndexPath: (record is a class variable)

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [FoodTypes TypeName:record.TypeId];
```

The FoodTypes class is declared as

```
@interface FoodTypes : NSObject {       
}

+(NSString*) TypeName: (NSNumber *) Type;
+(NSArray*) SubTypes: (NSNumber *)Type;
+(NSString*) SubType: (NSNumber *)Type atIndex:(NSNumber*)index;
+(NSString*) Unit: (NSNumber *) Type;
+(NSInteger) TypeCount;
@end
```

And it has `static NSArray *foodTypes_;` in the .m file. I don't know why the table is refreshed twice and is it supposed to happen twice? (The `record.TypeId` is consistent though)

The biggest problem is I don't know why `[FoodTypes TypeName]` works the first time but **returns nil** (thanks Eiko) the second time.

---

code when adding records:

```
FoodAddViewController *favCtrl = [[FoodAddViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FoodDetailView" bundle:nil];        
    favCtrl.delegate = self;

    NSManagedObjectContext *addingContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    self.addingManagedObjectContext = addingContext;       

    [addingManagedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[[fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext] persistentStoreCoordinator]];

    favCtrl.record = (FeedRecordClass*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"FeedRecord" inManagedObjectContext:addingContext] ;

    [favCtrl.record init];

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: favCtrl];

    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];    

    [favCtrl release];
    [addingContext release];
    [navController release];
```

Comment: You need to show more code. What does "fail" mean here? Is record.TypeId a valid value?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have Given delegate to tableview from nib. as well as you are reloading table from class file. checkout it.

Comment: the delegate is set when user press the "add" button, code is attached in my OP